# Printing Certain Area of a Windows Form

Tags: vb.net

I have my form with all my controls and everything is working as it should. I wish to print my panel named "Order" with the text box below and top of it. But only these objects.

My current code:

```
bmp = New Bitmap(DataGridView2.Width, DataGridView2.Height)
    Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    DataGridView2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, DataGridView2.ClientRectangle)
    G.Dispose()
    Dim int As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, int)
    Order.Text = (int + 1)
```

I can get it to print preview ( but it only shows the Datagridview and not the 2 textboxes above and below the gridview)

I cannot get it to print the extra textboxes and to skip the print preview and just go directly to print.

EDIT - I got everything showing now in the panel!

This is my current code to display the print preview:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    bmp = New Bitmap(Output.Width, Output.Height)
    Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Output.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Output.ClientRectangle)
    G.Dispose()
    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1


End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Ok so final issue is to skip print preview and just print immediately.

Comment: why don't you put the textboxes inside the panel and print the panel? or put them all inside another panel and print it? cause whatever you need to print would be easier for you if they are all inside 1 control which you can print easily..

Comment: I tried adding them all into another panel but it prints blank for some reason

Comment: Show us how you tried to print the other panel so we can help you

Comment: Edited my question with my updated coding :) Thank you

Comment: How about PrintDocument1.print()

Comment: Wonderful thank you that worked perfectly i will just do some edits on the form but otherwise im all set.

Comment: @OctaCode i cannot up vote you :( sorry can you submit a answer and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to put all the controls needed inside another panel and use document.print() to print directly without a viewer.

Glad i could help btw :)